# Equivalence Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I would appreciate any help available for the following problem:

Let $S$ be a set.  Let $T$ be the set of all relations on $S$.  Construct a relation $\equiv$ on $T$ in the following way:  for $\sim, \approx \in T$, say $\sim \equiv \approx$ if $\forall s,s' \in S, s \sim s' \implies s\approx s'$.  Determine whether $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on $T$, and if so, what its equivalence classes are.

What I did was this, however, I don't think it is correct.

Define a relation $@ \in T$ in the following way $\forall x,y \in S$, $x@y$ is not true, thus no elements in $S$ are related via $@$. The relation $\equiv$ is not an equivalence relation on T because it's not symmetric. Because if we let $@$ be the relation described, and let $@$ be the relation defined so that $\forall x,y \in S, x@y$ is true. Vacuously true statements would give $@ \equiv @$. But this is where I think I am going wrong because I don't know if S is a nonempty set?

Comment: Have you tried to do it by yourself? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: Tyr the case $|S|=1$. List all elements of $T$. Pick two relations $\sim,\approx\in T$ (there's little choice for picking). Is $\sim\equiv \approx$? Is $\approx\equiv \sim$? What if $S$ is any nonempty set? - And what if $S=\emptyset$?

Comment: I added what I tried to do but I am stuck on the cases and whether S is nonempty, because if so does that show it's not symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Let $R$ be the relation such that for every $x,y\in S$, $x\mathrel{R}y$. That is $R=S\times S$.

Show that every $\sim\in T$ has the property, $\sim\equiv\mathrel{R}$.